# I proper way to define the value in a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model:

```
class Cars < ActiveRecord::Base

  tag_nr = rand(2007)

end
```

The `Cars` model is mapped to the `cars` table in **database** with columns `name`, `owner`.

As you see above, there is also a `tag_nr` which is basically a **random number**.

I would like to have each **instance object** of `Cars` **class** hold a **random number** generated like above. **But** I do not want to have this random number be stored in database. And in future, I can access this instance object's `tag_nr` by:

```
nr = CAR_INSTANCE.tag_nr
```

And the `nr` now is the **same** as the `tag_nr` first generated for this Cars instance object.

So, where and how should I define this random number in my Car model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One easy way is with an `after_initialize` method:

```
class Cars < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize :init

  attr_accessor :tag_nr

  def init
    @tag_nr = rand(2007)
  end
end
```

This is now a callback method in 3.1 (3.0 as well?):

```
after_initialize do |car|
  puts "You have initialized an object!"
end
```

Comment: Is this method supported by Rails v2.3.2 ??

Comment: @Leem.fin [Yes (apidock docs)](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.2/Rails/Initializer/after_initialize), although your question is tagged with Rails 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can put that code into your 'lib' directory saving as find_random.rb

```
module FindRandom
  # pull out a unique set of random active record objects without killing
  # the db by using "order by rand()"
  # Note: not true-random, but good enough for rough-and-ready use
  #
  # The first param specifies how many you want.
  # You can pass in find-options in the second param
  # examples:
  #  Product.random     => one random product
  #  Product.random(3)  => three random products in random order
  #
  # Note - this method works fine with scopes too! eg:
  #  Product.in_stock.random    => one random product that fits the "in_stock" scope
  #  Product.in_stock.random(3) => three random products that fit the "in_stock" scope
  #  Product.best_seller.in_stock.random => one random product that fits both scopes
  #
  def find_random(num = 1, opts = {})
  # skip out if we don't have any
    return nil if (max = self.count(opts)) == 0

    # don't request more than we have
    num = [max,num].min

    # build up a set of random offsets to go find
    find_ids = [] # this is here for scoping

    # get rid of the trivial cases
    if 1 == num # we only want one - pick one at random
      find_ids = [rand(max)]
    else
      # just randomise the set of possible ids
      find_ids = (0..max-1).to_a.sort_by { rand }
      # then grab out the number that we need
      find_ids = find_ids.slice(0..num-1) if num != max
    end

    # we've got a random set of ids - now go pull out the records
    find_ids.map {|the_id| first(opts.merge(:offset => the_id)) }
  end
end
```

and extend your model like that

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FindRandom

  def self.tag_nr
    self.random
  end
end
```

Calling Car.tag_nr will give you an instance, but something is wrong with your code if you trying to create new instance using other same class instance.